# Not able to connect to mysql using terminal in mac osx

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal, phpmyadmin

I have installed zend server on my iMac. I can log on to zend server and i can log in to phpmyadmin, using user: root pw: (blank)

However. I am desperately trying to open mysql using the terminal. I have tried for 3h now and wiht all kinds of pathways and sudo-whatnot..

This i get when:

> Williams-iMac:mysql uglyface$ cd /usr/local/zend/mysql/bin
>
> Williams-iMac:bin uglyface$ ls

innochecksum            mysql_config            mysqlaccess.conf        mysqlhotcopy
msql2mysql          mysql_convert_table_format  mysqladmin          mysqlimport
my_print_defaults       mysql_find_rows         mysqladmin.client       mysqlmanager
myisam_ftdump           mysql_fix_extensions        mysqlbinlog         mysqlshow
myisamchk           mysql_fix_privilege_tables  mysqlbug            mysqlslap
myisamlog           mysql_secure_installation   mysqlcheck          mysqltest
myisampack          mysql_setpermission     mysqld              mysqltest_embedded
mysql               mysql_tzinfo_to_sql     mysqld-debug            perror
mysql.client            mysql_upgrade           mysqld_multi            replace
mysql.server            mysql_waitpid           mysqld_safe         resolve_stack_dump
mysql_client_test       mysql_zap           mysqldump           resolveip
mysql_client_test_embedded  mysqlaccess         mysqldumpslow           setup_mysql.sh

So in here i can se mysql, but i haven been able to do anything with it. I am sorry for way of displaying the output i get. I tried to get it to display differently but with no success as you can see...

Do any one know what i can do, so that i can log in to my mysql?

/W

edit: There is no mysql located in /usr/local/bin...

Comment: Have you started Mysql with the Zend server controller?  When Zend server is turned off, your Mysql is also off (usually).

Comment: hmm, how do i do that? I mean, i have the controller and all my options are turned on.

Answer (score 0):

If mysql is running (you start it with the zend server controller), you should be able to do:

```
 /usr/local/zend/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot -p <your dbname>
```

You can verify mysqld is running by a simple

```
 ps -ef | grep mysqld
```

If it's running, you'll see more than just your grep command in the resulting process list.

Comment: Thank you! When i entered the dbname too, it worked. I think i read that its possible to kinda create a shortcut for connecting to mysql and a db, do you know if that is possible, and if, how do i do it? Further more, how do i change the password? For root? Thank you!